# NuxtUI Table - How to edit only specific row

Tags: nuxt.js

I need to use slot only in the first row with the id 1.
I am using **NuxtUI** table components

```js
<script setup>
  const columns = [{
    key: 'name',
    label: 'Name'
  }, {
    key: 'title',
    label: 'Title'
  }]
  
  const people = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Team',
    title: 'Red Bull'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Country',
    title: 'Netherlands'
  }]

<UTable :rows="people" :columns="columns">
  <template #title-data="{ row }">
   <NuxtLink to="/redbull">RedBull Racing Team</NuxtLink>
  </template>
</UTable>
```